# How to delete first 5 line of specific column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (pandas) with columns A to J. I want to remove the first 7 lines from column A.

I know: a function form remove the entre column. But How can I remove the first 7 lines from the specific column?

```
df.drop(['your_column_name'], axis=1, inplace=True)


    #A
    #B
    #C
    #D  
    #F
    #G 
    #H
    #I
    #J

   #Index   #A      #B
    #0      #NAN    #234
    #1      #NAN    #235
    #2      #NAN    #236
    #3      #NAN    #237
    #4      #NAN    #238
    #5      #NAN    #239
    #6      #NAN    #240
    #7      #123    #241
    #8      #124    #245
    #9      #125    #236
    #10     #126    #4562
```

Comment: what happens to the first 7 lines in other columns?

Comment: I want to remove the first 7 lines from column A because those are NAN. So I want to remove the first 7 lines from Column A

Comment: @Mr.Asif - If you "remove" those values, you must ensure that column is of equal size as the other columns. So, you have two choices, 1. delete the first 7 rows of the whole dataframe, 2. replace the `NaN` values with something else, like `0`.

Comment: You can not have dataframe with columns of different lengths. So in principal, what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: So if I want to remove 7 rows from entire dataset how may I write the code ?

Comment: df.drop(df.index[:7], inplace=True)

this function is workable for deleting first 7 rows of entire dataset

Answer (score 1):

In case you will remove the whole rows which contain NAN, you can use simply

```
df.dropna()
```

However you can't remove particular row from specified dataframe column because each row indexed by default which means all columns in a row cohere, and if you remove rows from first column the other columns are longer which is not possible.